# Asp.Net / Ajax -> different routes when on a local IIS web server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, iis-10

A small question that will certainly seem simple (im new).

I developed a project in Asp.net MVC with ajax / jquery.
I then published my project on my local web server (via IIS10).
I have some routes that have become untraceable ... However, I noticed via the web debugger that my parameters are sometimes passed differently.

Would you have an idea to fix that?

```
         function GetEdit() {
         $("#UsersDatatables").on('click', '.edit', (function () {
             var id = this.id;
             $('#myModalLabel').text("Edit User");

             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "/User/EditDelete/" + id,
                 datatype: "json",
                 data: { id: id },
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#USE_Id").val(data['USE_Id'])
                     $("#FirstName").val(data['USE_FirstName']);
                     $("#LastName").val(data['USE_LastName']);

                     if (data['USE_Gender'] == '0')
                         $("#Female").prop("checked", true);
                     else
                         $("#Male").prop("checked", true);

                     $("#Gender").val(data['USE_Gender']);
                     $("#Country").val(data['USE_CountryID']);
                     $("#Email").val(data['USE_EmailAddress']);
                     $("#PhoneNumber").val(data['USE_PhoneNumber']);
                     $("#GroupDrop").val("");
                     $('#myModal').modal('show');
                 },
                 error: function (error) {
                     toastr.error("The user update could not be performed.");
                 }
             });
         }));
     }
```

This is the route seen in the debugger:

```
http://localhost/User/EditDelete/2?id=2
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `data: { id: id }` part from the ajax settings;
for a `GET` request, it causes the `id` to be appended to the url as querystring.

```
function GetEdit() {
     $("#UsersDatatables").on('click', '.edit', (function () {
         var id = this.id;
         $('#myModalLabel').text("Edit User");

         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/User/EditDelete/" + id,
             datatype: "json",                 
             success: function (data) {
                 $("#USE_Id").val(data['USE_Id'])
                 $("#FirstName").val(data['USE_FirstName']);
                 $("#LastName").val(data['USE_LastName']);

                 if (data['USE_Gender'] == '0')
                     $("#Female").prop("checked", true);
                 else
                     $("#Male").prop("checked", true);

                 $("#Gender").val(data['USE_Gender']);
                 $("#Country").val(data['USE_CountryID']);
                 $("#Email").val(data['USE_EmailAddress']);
                 $("#PhoneNumber").val(data['USE_PhoneNumber']);
                 $("#GroupDrop").val("");
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');
             },
             error: function (error) {
                 toastr.error("The user update could not be performed.");
             }
         });
     }));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help dude!